# How to fail a python unittest in setUpClass?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

I am doing some unittests with python and some pre-test checks in `setUpClass`. How can I throw a `unitest`-`fail` within the `setUpClass`, as the following simple example:

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):    
        unittest.TestCase.fail("Test")

    def test1(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

gives the error `TypeError: unbound method fail() must be called with TestCase instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`.

I understand the error I get as fail is a instance method, and I don't have an instance of `MyClass` yet. Using an instance on-the-fly like

```
unittest.TestCase().fail("Test")
```

also does not work, as `unittest.TestCase` itself has no tests. Any ideas how to fail all tests in `MyClass`, when some condition in `setUpClass` is not met?

Followup question: Is there a way to see the tests in `setUpClass`?

Comment: it is also possible to skip test (for anyone who do not want to have a fail and still test the rest): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066508/disable-individual-python-unit-tests-temporarily

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`self.fail("test")` put into your setUp instance method fails all the tests

I think the easiest way to do this at the class level is to make a class variable so something like:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
   cls.flag = False

def setUp(self):
   if self.flag:
       self.fail("conditions not met")
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: for some reason sonarqube does not accept the self.fail line. for me it says that it's not covered by tests.

Answer (score 50):

Using a simple assert should work

```
assert False, "I mean for this to fail"
```

Comment: Won't this report from the test runner as an error rather than a failure?

Comment: Doesn't AssertionError being raised mean the test fails?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in python but with same problem, I've resolved adding cls param:

```
...
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.fail(cls, "Test") 
...
```

I think is strange but clearer.

When you pass cls, warning appear (Expected type 'TestCase', got 'Type[MyTests]' instead) and MyTests inherits from TestCase thus can
ignoring adding: # noinspection PyTypeChecker