# Disable a Python unit test with a message

Tags: python, unit-testing

My version of Python does not support

```
    @unittest.skip("demonstrating skipping")
```

from *[Disable individual Python unit tests temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066508/how-to-disable-individual-tests-temporarily-using-unittest-module-in-python)*, I understand how to use a decorator to achieve this, i.e.,

```
def disabled(f):
    def _decorator():
        print f.__name__ + ' has been disabled'
    return _decorator

@disabled
def testFoo():
    '''Foo test case'''
    print 'this is foo test case'

testFoo()
```

However, the decorator does not support providing a message for the skipping. May I know how I can achieve this please? I basically want something like

```
def disabled(f, msg):
    def _decorator():
        print f.__name__ + ' has been disabled' + msg
    return _decorator

@disabled("I want to skip it")
def testFoo():
    '''Foo test case'''
    print 'this is foo test case'

testFoo()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the decorator like so:

```
def disabled(msg):
    def _decorator(f):
        def _wrapper():
            print f.__name__ + ' has been disabled ' + msg
        return _wrapper
    return _decorator


@disabled("I want to skip it")
def testFoo():
    '''Foo test case'''
    print 'this is foo test case'


testFoo()
```