# How do I disable a test using pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Let's say I have a bunch of tests:

```
def test_func_one():
    ...

def test_func_two():
    ...

def test_func_three():
    ...
```

Is there a decorator or something similar that I could add to the functions to prevent `pytest` from running just that test? The result might look something like...

```
@pytest.disable()
def test_func_one():
    ...

def test_func_two():
    ...

def test_func_three():
    ...
```

Comment: Under the hood the custom exception `_pytest.outcomes.Skipped` is raised to skip a test

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Pytest has the skip and skipif decorators, similar to the Python unittest module (which uses `skip` and `skipIf`), which can be found in the documentation [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/skipping.html#skipping-test-functions).

Examples from the link can be found here:

```
@pytest.mark.skip(reason="no way of currently testing this")
def test_the_unknown():
    ...

import sys
@pytest.mark.skipif(sys.version_info < (3,3),
                    reason="requires python3.3")
def test_function():
    ...
```

The first example always skips the test, the second example allows you to conditionally skip tests (great when tests depend on the platform, executable version, or optional libraries.

For example, if I want to check if someone has the library pandas installed for a test.

```
import sys
try:
    import pandas as pd
except ImportError:
    pass

@pytest.mark.skipif('pandas' not in sys.modules,
                    reason="requires the Pandas library")
def test_pandas_function():
    ...
```

Comment: Is there anything similar to the elegant ``.skip`` that Mocha (Node.js) has?
``it('tests something'...)`` --> ``it.skip('tests something'...)`` which would disable that particular test. It also has the handy opposite: ``.only`` which will only run that test and nothing else.

Comment: I mean, for the `only` part, you may do that via the command line or whatever you use to initializer the test runner:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36539692/4131059

As for the `it` and `it.skip`, I believe the functionality here fully covers that.

Comment: Another useful thing is to skipif using a function call. You can get the function to return a dictionary containing `condition` and `reason` properties, and then use `@pytest.mark.skipif(**myFunction())` to automatically unwrap the function arguments.

Answer (score 53):

The [`skip` decorator](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#marking-a-test-function-to-be-skipped) would do the job:

```
@pytest.mark.skip(reason="no way of currently testing this")
def test_func_one():
    # ...
```

(`reason` argument is optional, but it is always a good idea to specify why a test is skipped).

There is also [`skipif()`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#id1) that allows to disable a test if some specific condition is met.

---

These decorators can be applied to methods, functions or classes.

To [skip all tests in a module](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#skip-all-test-functions-of-a-class-or-module), define a global `pytestmark` variable:

```
# test_module.py
pytestmark = pytest.mark.skipif(...)
```

Answer (score 40):

You can mark a test with the `skip` and `skipif` decorators when you want to skip a test in [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html).

#### Skipping a test

```py
@pytest.mark.skip(reason="no way of currently testing this")
def test_func_one():
    ...
```

The simplest way to skip a test is to mark it with the `skip` decorator which may be passed an optional `reason`.

It is also possible to skip imperatively during test execution or setup by calling the `pytest.skip(reason)` function. This is useful when it is not possible to evaluate the skip condition during import time.

```py
def test_func_one():
    if not valid_config():
        pytest.skip("unsupported configuration")
```

#### Skipping a test based on a condition

```py
@pytest.mark.skipif(sys.version_info < (3, 6), reason="requires python3.6 or higher")
def test_func_one():
    ...
```

If you want to skip based on a conditional then you can use `skipif` instead. In the previous example, the test function is skipped when run on an interpreter earlier than Python3.6.

Finally, if you want to skip a test because you are sure it is failing, you might also consider using the [`xfail`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#xfail-mark-test-functions-as-expected-to-fail) marker to indicate that you expect a test to fail.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to skip the test but not hard code a marker, better use keyword expression to escape it.

```
pytest test/test_script.py -k 'not test_func_one'
```

Note: Here '**keyword expression**' is basically, expressing something using keywords provided by pytest (or python) and getting something done. In above example, '***not***' is a keyword.

For more info, refer this [link](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/usage.html?highlight=keyword%20expression#).

More examples of keyword expression can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869181/1076965) answer.

Comment: What is *"keyword expression"*? Do you mean *"keyword suppression"*? In any case, can you add a reference to it? But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I added a bit more. Do tell if that helps.

Answer (score 23):

I'm not sure if it's deprecated, but you can also use the `pytest.skip` function inside of a test:

```
def test_valid_counting_number():
     number = random.randint(1,5)
     if number == 5:
         pytest.skip('Five is right out')
     assert number <= 3
```

Comment: came for the pytest help, stayed for the reference

Comment: what does it reference. I have to know

Comment: @XChikuX https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOrgLj9lOwk

Comment: I'm afraid this was well before my time. But, I'm glad I know it now.

Answer (score 13):

You may also want to run the test even if you suspect that test will fail. For such scenario https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html suggests to use decorator **@pytest.mark.xfail**

```
@pytest.mark.xfail
def test_function():
    ...
```

In this case, Pytest will still run your test and let you know if it passes or not, but won't complain and break the build.

Comment: Nice one - been reading around pytest for > 12 months and hadn't come across this - thanks for calling it out.  Great strategy so that failing tests (that need some love and care) don't get forgotten (or deleted!)

Answer (score 6):

You can divide your tests on set of test cases by custom pytest markers, and execute only those test cases what you want. Or the inverse, running all tests except the another set:

```
@pytest.mark.my_unit_test
def test_that_unit():
...

@pytest.mark.my_functional_test
def test_that_function():
...
```

And then, to run only one set of unit tests, as example:
`pytest -m my_unit_test`

Inverse, if you want to run all tests, except one set:
`pytest -m "not my_unit_test"`

[How to combine several marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761243/how-to-specify-several-marks-for-the-pytest-command)

[More examples in official documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/markers.html)

It looks more convenient if you have good logic separation of test cases.

Answer (score 2):

People have spoken of the `skip` decorator. Works like a charm!

A better way to set this up is with the `skipif` decorator which allows you to skip certain tests conditionally.

This is a construct I love to use especially for long tests.

```py
import pytest
import os

# your skipif decorator to conditionally skip a test that takes too long
@pytest.mark.skipif("RUNALL" not in os.environ, reason="takes too long")
def test_a_very_long_process():
   # Your test code...
```

What this does is that it will check that the environment variable `RUNALL` exists. If not, it will skip those tests.

This means that the usual `pytest` command will skip those tests. However, when the time to run all tests (like when going into production mode) comes, you can run `RUNALL=true pytest`.

Of course you can evaluate any other conditions with [skipif](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/skipping.html#marking-a-test-function-to-be-skipped) :)

Comment: I used pytest.mark.skip() without any condition because I just wanted to skip the test as I wanted to focus on one testing that was on the same file.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to disable an entire testclass, you can use the `__test__ = False`

We use it in large testsuites for spesific test that we only run on special occations, like long lasting regression tests or tests that always fails.

We then set an environment variable like:
`export SCIM_GROUP_REGRESSION_TEST=1`
if we want to run it

```
SCIM_GROUP_REGRESSION_TEST = False
if os.environ.get('SCIM_GROUP_REGRESSION_TEST'):
    SCIM_GROUP_REGRESSION_TEST = True

class TestClass:
    __test__ = SCIM_GROUP_REGRESSION_TEST
    :
    <your tests>
```

Then you explicitly need to set this environment-variable to run it, in all other occations it will be skipped

Answer (score 0):

The `__test__` attribute (documented for `TestXxx` classes [here](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#customizing-test-collection)) also works for functions:

```
def test_something():
    ...

test_something.__test__ = False
```

The Pytest 2.6 [changelog](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#id530) says:

> support nose-style `__test__` attribute on modules, classes and functions, including unittest-style Classes. If set to False, the test will not be collected.