# How do I ignore a failing test?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a failing test that I want to commit to version control. I don't have time to fix it right now but I don't want to comment it out or delete it. I've added a TODO to fix it later.

I don't want the test to run when I run all my other tests.

*How do I ignore a test with pytest?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How do I disable a test using py.test?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38442948/11809808)