# How to specify several marks for the pytest command

Tags: python, pytest

Reading http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html I see the example of including or excluding certain python tests based on a mark.

Including:

```
pytest -v -m webtest
```

Excluding:

```
pytest -v -m "not webtest"
```

What if I would like to specify several marks for both include and exclude?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `and`/`or` to combine multiple markers, same as for `-k` selector. Example test suite:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.foo
def test_spam():
    assert True


@pytest.mark.foo
def test_spam2():
    assert True


@pytest.mark.bar
def test_eggs():
    assert True


@pytest.mark.foo
@pytest.mark.bar
def test_eggs2():
    assert True


def test_bacon():
    assert True
```

Selecting all tests marked with `foo` and not marked with `bar`

```
$ pytest -q --collect-only -m "foo and not bar"
test_mod.py::test_spam
test_mod.py::test_spam2
```

Selecting all tests marked neither with `foo` nor with `bar`

```
$ pytest -q --collect-only -m "not foo and not bar"
test_mod.py::test_bacon
```

Selecting tests that are marked with any of `foo`, `bar`

```
$ pytest -q --collect-only -m "foo or bar"
test_mod.py::test_spam
test_mod.py::test_spam2
test_mod.py::test_eggs
test_mod.py::test_eggs2
```