# Ignoring function to be tested in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a scenario where I want the pytest not to test the function and resume the test excution.

```
def test(self):
    self.test1()
    self.test2()
    self.test3()
```

Here I want to ignore/skip `self.test2()` method to be executed. How can I proceed by simply ignoring `self.test2()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable a test using pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442897/how-do-i-disable-a-test-using-pytest)

Comment: No. I am not looking for skipping a test for test execution. Here I am looking a way by the help of which I can skip a part of function under test. self.test2() is a function in a flow of test(self). I want to skip that like if we comment self.test2() then it wont get executed .

Comment: Under what condition do you want to skip the call to `self.test2()` ? If always why don't you just remove the line ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. You just have to mock the function.
Here in this case

```
obj = test()
obj.test2 = Mock()
```