# Ignore function in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Is there a way to ignore whole function in python/pytest? For example:

```
def function1():
    print("function1")
def function2():
    print("function2")
def function3():
    function1()
    function2()
@patch("function2")
def test_function3():
    function3()
>>> function2
```

Comment: How about using `skip`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442897/how-do-i-disable-a-test-using-pytest

Comment: @user107511 of course I expect answer like this. I don't want to skip test - I want to skip particular function in testing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install pytest-mock and change your test as followed:

```
from pytest_mock import MockerFixture

def test_function3(mocker: MockerFixture):
    mocker.patch("function2", return_value=None)
    function3(
```