# How to optionally skip long tests in Python Unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Some of my tests are taking long time, and I want to have an option to run only short tests or all tests. I have found option to disable some tests ([Disable individual Python unit tests temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066508/disable-individual-python-unit-tests-temporarily)), but I didn't find option to, for example, set some flag in `python -m unittest` run those disabled tests anyway. What's the best practice here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am using unittest, not pytest.

Comment: Ah, sorry - as far as I know, there is no such flag in unittest. You could use `skipif`instead and check for some environment variable, which you have to set if you want to run (or skip) the tests.

Comment: That seems to work, thank you very much!